# PHP printf function and it's weird behaviour

Tags: php, integer, printf

I'm baffled what these numbers mean. To me it seems that printf gives me wrong results.

```
echo printf("%.2f", 1);
// 1.004

echo printf("%.3f", 1);
// 1.005

echo printf("%.2f", 1.1234);
// 1.124
```

First of all it seems to print too many decimals and I have no idea what those numbers are. Can someone shed some light on this matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple. [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/printf) has a return value, which is integer. And that value is - length of resulting string. Thus, your code is doing two things:

- First, format & output your string with `printf()`
- Second, `echo()` the result, which is the length for each string.

That is because you see `1.004` for first case, for example. It's `1.00` with `4` (and length of `"1.00"` string is `4`)

If your intention is to print formatted string, either use `printf()` as it is:

```
printf("%.2f", 1);
```

Or use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) with echo:

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", 1);
```